Was Jesus already in the likeness of a man spiritually before the creation of Adam?
The book of Genesis has a lot of mysteries encoded in it, apart from God using a plural term to refer to himself alongside other beings to create, there is another mystery where a being referred to as Yahweh God apparently walks in the garden like a man. Was Adam made in the image of Jesus Christ? and was Jesus already in the form or in the image of a man before he created Adam out of the mud?
Genesis 3:8

In the cool of the evening, the man and his wife heard Yahweh God walking around in the garden. So they hid from Yahweh God among the trees in the garden.

How is it possible for Yahweh God to walk unless it is Jesus for the Father is omnipresent? Did Jesus have this likeness of a man since time eternal?

Yes, the Word, or Logos, was not a created being and was divine.  It was not until he came to earth that he took on humanity and was known as Jesus. I'm struggling to understand why you refer to the pre-incarnate Son of God as Jesus.

@Lesley, because he will be referred to with that name for all of eternal future by the saints, for now he is the lamb. If that holds then Adam is made in the image of Jesus

This is primarily a theological question, not an interpretative question about Genesis.

This literal translation of the text in question is worth comparing with the one you provided (and could you state what that translation was, please?):

"And they hear the sound of Jehovah God walking up and down in the
garden at the breeze of the day, and the man and his wife hide
themselves from the face of Jehovah God in the midst of the trees of
the garden. And Jehovah God calleth unto the man, and saith to him,
'Where [art] thou?' And he saith, 'Thy sound I have heard in the
garden, and I am afraid...'  Genesis 3:8-10 Young's Literal
Translation

Nowhere does the text even hint that Jehovah God apparently walks like a man in the garden. It only states that his moving around the garden creates a sound of walking. Certainly, the verse in question has Jehovah God speaking to the hidden man, who hid at the sound of God in the garden. This denotes an audible contact, so there does not seem to be warrant to suppose that God walks like a man at that time.
The question, however, focuses on "whether Jesus was already in the likeness of a man before Adam was created". First, the man, Jesus, would not walk the Earth as a man until thousands of years after the creation of Adam. The Bible elsewhere tells us that the Word of God (who is also the Son of God) existed with God in the beginning, before any creation started. So, I would rephrase your question as, "Was the Word of God already in the likeness of a man spiritually before the creation of Adam?"
But this is your question - not mine! My answer is based on going back to Genesis 1:26-27. Note that the word translated as 'Jehovah' does not crop up at all in this first account of this creation. Chapter 2 verse 4 is the first time 'Jehovah' is used. So, here is the significant point about 'likeness':

"And God 'saith', 'Let Us make man in Our image, according to Our
likeness... And God prepareth the man in His image; in the image of
God He prepared him, a male and a female He prepared them." Genesis
1:26-27 YLT

The Bible is clear that God is Spirit. When we read of God creating this man in his image, in his likeness, that should determine the need to turn the whole concept of likeness around, seeing that it must be a spiritual likeness, not a physical one. This instantly rules out the idea of God having feet, like a man, in order to walk on the earth like a man does.
But the eternal Son of God is also the Word of God, and God speaks in the garden.
Adam had spiritual 'likeness' to his Maker, and we also read in the Bible that this Word of God, who was with God in the beginning, and who was God, made everything that was made. The Word was spoken at creation, and what God spoke is recorded for us in the opening chapters of Genesis (and throughout the rest of the Bible.)
It seems safe to say that God communicates with humanity verbally - through his Word - whether audibly as with some individuals (like Adam and Abraham and Moses etc) or in written form (the Bible). It does not seem safe to say that God has literal feet of flesh like a man. However, it is entirely safe to say that when the Word became flesh, as the virgin Mary's child, he did have the feet of a human, and he did walk on the earth as men do. And, as man was made in the image / likeness of God spiritually, there was nothing strange about the Word becoming flesh, adding to his divine nature what he had created, in his likeness - human nature.

Thanks for your input, Moses wrote and didn't write his own imaginations but what he heard from the Holy Spirit, The Lord God literally walked which means he did like man, we are made in the image of Yashua Ha Mashiach
